# Popup windows - Browser differences

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I am creating popup windows using window.open and setting the height and width of the created screen.

The navigation bar always appears (since this is a browser setting beyond my control). The problem is in IE/Firefox the navigation bar is excluded from the height I define which is good, but in Chrome, it is not, so my popup ends up being undersized with a right scrollbar.

What's the preferred mechanism for dealing with this.

Using a function to set the popup-height which checks the browser type and adds adjustments depending on the result?

```
 function popupCreator(url, popupname, height, width){

    if(browsertype=="chrome"){  //obviously not this exact code!
        height = height + 20;
    }

    var params = 'width=' + width + ',height=' + height;
    newwin = window.open(url, popupname, params);

 }
```

Or is there a better way of achieving this?

The full function I am currently using:

```
 "popup": function (url, popupname, height, width) {
    if (null == width) {
        var width = screen.width / 2;
    }
    if (null == height) {
        var height = screen.height / 2;
    }

    var left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
    var top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
    var params = 'width=' + width + ',height=' + height;
    params += ',top=' + top + ',left=' + left;
    params += ',directories=no';
    params += ',location=no';
    params += ',menubar=no';
    params += ',resizable=no';
    params += ',scrollbars=no';
    params += ',status=no';
    params += ',toolbar=no';
    params += ',dialog=yes';
    params += ',titlebar=no';
    newwin = window.open(url, popupname, params);
    if (window.focus) { newwin.focus() }
    return false;
},
```

Comment: You're misinterpreting those parameters. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.open the `height` and `width` values don't include anything other than your screen area and scrollbars. Chrome included, does not include the navigation bar in those calculations.

Comment: I thought we left pop-up windows behind in the 90s :(

Comment: and do NOT have spaces in the parm. Many older browsers don't like that

Comment: In Chrome, using the same parameters for height and width, my popup is smaller by exactly the height of the navigation bar. The link you send me is Mozilla - I have no issues with FF implementation - Only Chrome seems to shrink my window.

Comment: if (window.focus) is a remnant of IE3.02 - not needed. Better use if (newwin) { newwin.focus(); return false}; return true; // if onclick of a link

Comment: @Tomalak - this is a RIA application - not a website as such

Comment: @mplungjan - thanks - hadn't noticed that until you mentioned it

Comment: I know MDN is mozilla based, but their documentation on the matter is inclusive - that's why I used the explicit phrase "Chrome included". For example, a simple `window.open('http://google.com', 'foo', 'width=200,height=200')` on Chrome 12 yields this: http://dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=eq2mp9oaxuh3vm88dzof.png Count the pixels yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visibility of navigation bar is controllable. For instance:

```
window.open('http://some-url', 'window-name',
    'location=yes,links=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,width=716,height=480');
```

Location is the only thing that cannot be hidden, because of security reasons.

Comment: The location bar is another name for the navigation bar.

Comment: @Quentin No, Navigation bar includes controls. Location bar is for location only.

Comment: OK - fair point - it's the location bar that in Chrome causes the issue.

Comment: @BonyT a little strange that you have such an issue, because I don't see such an issue on my Chrome 12 (Windows).

Comment: @BonyT I have even tested the code you gave and it works fine and the same on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: odd - it most definitely has the above issue when I try it - also Chrome 12, on Windows 7. The popup is quite complex, I will try and recreate the problem in a simpler manner.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of the same code

I assume you do a `return popup(this.href,this.target,500,600)` in a link

```
"popup": function (url, popupname, height, width) {
    var w = width  || screen.width  / 2;
    var h = height || screen.height / 2;
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') != -1) h+=20;
    var left = (screen.width - w) / 2;
    var top  = (screen.height - h) / 2;
    var params = 'width=' + w + ',height=' + h;
    params += ',top=' + top + ',left=' + left;
    params += ',screenY=' + top + ',screenX=' + left; // let's support older NS too ;)

    // all params that are not mentioned are off per default, 
    // all params mentioned are true per default
//    params += ',directories=no';
//    params += ',location=no';
//    params += ',menubar=no';
    params += ',resizable'; // given as an example of a =yes
//    params += ',scrollbars=no';
//    params += ',status=no';
//    params += ',toolbar=no';
    params += ',dialog'; // NS/FF only thing
//    params += ',titlebar=no';
    var newwin = window.open(url, popupname, params);
    if (newwin) { 
      newwin.focus(); 
      return false; // cancel the href
    }
    return true; // follow the href, the window was blocked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since chrome is using inner syntax and the other browser dont, you can just use this in the code aswell. and get it this easy!

```
window.open('http://some-url', 'window-name',
'location=yes,links=no,scrollbars=yes,width=716,height=480,innerHeight=510');
```

You are welcome! :D